# Determine boundaries of sheet music for cropping

Tags: c#

I have thousands of images of sheet music, in 4:3 aspect ratio, that I want to crop to something closer to 16:9. The images have a lot of whitespace, so at least I want to cut that away.

All the images are different, even the margins aren't always the same.

What kind of algorithm should I use in C# to detect the edges of the staves, so I can determine where to crop the image? 
(The green box is where I'd want to crop this image)

I've tried looping through all the pixels, that seems to work, but is extremely inefficient. 
[image]
Is there a better way?

Comment: You don't need to loop _all_ the pixels. If you go line-by-line, you can stop at the first non-"white" pixel from left and right, respecively. (Assuming you have done binarization, already.) That should speed up the algorithm. And after having found the first one, you can even stop if the line doesn't have a more extreme point. You would only have to account for the things like that little "Lied 1:1" in the top-center, there.

Comment: What image format is that, btw?

Comment: Right. That would probably make it faster. It's PNG.

Comment: If you can’t find an efficient way to do this and you wish to consider using a professional imaging library, try the [AutoCropCommand class](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/po/autocropcommand.html) from LEADTOOLS Imaging Pro SDK. (Disclosure: I work for the SDK’s vendors). You simply need to call `Leadtools.RasterCodecs.Load(<any image format>)`, use AutoCrop on the loaded image then call `Leadtools.RasterCodecs.Save(<same format or any other>)`. There’s a free evaluation on [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).